# In Python, why does the lowest (smallest) floating point value have different significant-digits than the largest?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just read in a Machine Learning for Dummies book that the smallest non-zero value for a floating point variable is `2.2250738585082014x10^-308` and that the largest value is `1.7976931348623157x10^308`.

What is the explanation for this?

Why is it not the same value for positive and negative exponents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All floating point numbers (double is a double-precision float) are written as a product of two values, the mantissa and the exponent.

The way the floating point number exponent is stored uses 8 bits (for floats) or 11 bits (for doubles), meaning you get exponent values of -127 to +128 (float) or -1023 to +1024 (double).

And 2^1024 gives us a value of 1.797693134862315907729305190789 * 10^308, which is the largest exponent of a double precision float.

Have a demo in [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

For Python, a detail explanation can be found in the page "Floating Point Arithmetic: [Issues and Limitations"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in the Python tutorial.

Comment: So it's smaller because of the "negative marker" on the exponent?

Comment: @hugo_leonardo  that would make sense, can someone verify this?

Comment: [Here is the IEEE standard document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [here is the Python documentation referencing the same](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.float_info)

Comment: And if you want to check for yourself what you min/max are `sys.float_info` will give you them.

Comment: This explains the largest value, as `2^1024` matches `sys.float_info.max` (`1.7976931348623157e+308`). But `2^-1023` doesn't match `sys.float_info.min` (`2.2250738585072014e-308`)! In fact, usual double-precision floating-point numbers can't have an effective exponent of `-1023` - the all-zero-bits exponent value is treated specially, & thus doesn't indicate a `-1023` exponent, but rather `-1022`-but-with-a-'denormalized'-mantissa (the implied-leading `1.` is dropped). So, `2^-1022` matches `2.2250738585072014e-308`. (And, even-smaller denormalized values are possible, but rarely considered!)